# check if user is signed into a browser

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible to use JavaScript to check if a user is signed into Chrome or Safari browser?

I've checked the `window.navigator` object and looked in the application tab in chrome dev tools.

---

To clarify for those who did not understand my original question, *signed into* means the user has signed-in to chrome.  See the below links for more information on signing in to a browser...
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27441

Also, this question is not
a duplicate of [check if user is signed into a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820163/check-if-user-is-signed-into-a-browser), which is about detecting a user's browser. This question ia about identifying if a user is **signed into** a browser.

Comment: "signed in"? There is a navigator.online - but what do you mean by "signed in"

Comment: You would probably have to deploy/use google's sign-in api (ie like facebook sign in) to detect that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza this question is not about detecting the users browser

Comment: I updated the question to help clarify